# Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC") - ClassNotFound - Java Applet

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, applet

i have an **JavaApplet** and start this in **HTML** on **IE** with a sqlite-database.

So i got an exception like this..

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

```
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at sqliteConnection.dbConnector(sqliteConnection.java:10)
at ResponsibilitySearch$1.run(ResponsibilitySearch.java:54)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` -> This means the class was not found during runtime. You have to make it available for the program, by adding it to the classpath. Get the jar from here: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. In Eclipse the sqlite is in build path and the programm is running.. as an execute jar is also running. But on IE it doesn't